# "Много что можно" - можно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Идём? Можно ведь и сесть пообедать. Тут много что можно попробовать.
>   Мы же уже в Италии!

Или рисовать "Тут много такого, что стоит попробовать"? Иль ещё что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректно: много **чего** можно (сделать).

Из Нацкорпуса:

> Тем более что на этом поле еще **много чего можно сделать**. [Иван Рубанов. Крест на «русский крест» // «Эксперт», 2014]
>
> Толковая идея, ей-богу: частная художественная студия для детей; а там уже **много чего можно складировать** среди рисунков и акварелей, созданных трогательной детской рукой. [Дина Рубина. Белая голубка Кордовы (2008-2009)]
>
> За пятилетний срок полномочий **много чего можно порешать** ― до конца жизни хватит и детям останется. [Виктор Попов. Обдемократились, блин! (2003) // «Калининградская правда», 2003.06.10]

Но гораздо лучше Ваш вариант: **"Тут много такого, что стоит попробовать".**
Два "можно" подряд делали речь убогой.

Comment: А за этим есть какая-нибудь теория? В "корпусе" достаточно много иных примеров из книг, просто их не сразу видно из-за более частого стечения этих слов через запятую.

Comment: @Alex_ander Вопрос не понял. О чем он? О теории, стоящей за чем? Или о том, как я сформулировал запрос?

Comment: О том, почему "много чего" корректно, а "много что", соответсвенно, - нет. Такое сопоставление где-нибудь рассматривалось на предмет корректности одного из двух или вывод основан на существованиии примеров употребления?

Comment: Теория говорит, что "мого" как числительное в именительном и винительном падеже управляет существительным в родительном. У нас — местоимением в родительном.  Также отсутствуют примеры типа "много что" в Нацкорпусе.

Comment: Знаю такую теорию только в отношении случая с отрицанием, сейчас приведу в ответе литер. примеры из того же корпуса, "их там есть".

Answer (score 3):

Мало что находится (= можно найти) из толкований по данному вопросу. Книжные примеры в "корпусе" для "много что" в винительном:

> Там директор много что собрал ― вазы, монеты, три статуи. [Ю. О.
> Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 2 (1978)]
> (ещё два случая с винительным падежом в том же произведении)
>
> С Курмышовым у Алеши сложились добрые отношения, тем более что Алеша в
> свои 10 лет уже много что умел, а Лёня пока еще не умел ничего...
> [Александра Маринина. Последний рассвет (2013)]
>
> Развитие таких языков с большей вероятностью шло в обществах, где
> людям было много что сказать друг другу...  [Карл Левитин. Изреченная
> мысль. Встреча четвертая // «Знание - сила», 2009]
>
> Поведение других людей много что улучшает в мире, но только наше
> изменит в нем всё. [В. В. Бибихин. Вступление (2003)]
>
> И много что в беспамятстве и освобожденности говорят живые, но,
> проснувшись, не помнят и ищут последним зряшным видениям случайные
> отгадки». [Игорь Сухих. Однажды была земля // «Звезда», 2002]
>
> ..........................

Если речь идёт о множественных *счётных* сущностях (попробовать в значении  возможности "съесть" одно блюдо и многие другие), то правильнее "**много что**". Оправдание же родительному падежу (много чего *попробовать*) при отсутствии отрицания возможно в значении *дегустации*: "попробовать (немного) того,  (немного) другого... и так много раз" - родительный падеж в таких случаях берётся **не** от числительного "много" в винительном, а от падежного сочетания с подразумеваемым неопределённым числительным (немного, сколько-то, часть чего):

> **Чего** вы хотели бы отведать (попробовать)? - **Много чего** (кусочек этого,
> чуть-чуть этого).

А для счётных сущностей склонение сочетания "много что" затрагивает только местоимение:

- И. много что (есть)
- Р. много чего (остатки, нет, не хватает, нельзя посмотреть)
- Д. много чему (посвятить)
- В. много что (можно посмотреть это, это и это... всего не перечислить)
- Т. много чем (спекулируют)
- П. много о чём (судачат)

В данном случае я на стороне автора: он явно не имеет в виду дегустацию.

Comment: Может, Вы и правы. Тогда то, что написано о количественно-именных сочетаниях (например, *много стульев*) нельзя распространять на "много что".